# Unable to put a Boost Thread asleep

Tags: boost

OS: Win7
IDE: Visual Studio 2010
Boost Version: 1.47

I'm new to Boost and what I'm trying is very simple.  I've created a single thread in a header file and tried putting it to sleep.  But I can't get it working.  Here is the code and compilation errors

main.h -

```
#pragma once   
#include <conio.h>   
#include <boost\thread.hpp>   

boost::posix_time::seconds workTime ( 120 );  
boost::this_thread::sleep ( workTime );
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"  

void main ( void ) {
    _getch();
};
```

Output -

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2365: 'boost::this_thread::sleep' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
error C2491: 'boost::this_thread::sleep' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
error C2482: 'boost::this_thread::sleep' : dynamic initialization of 'thread' data not allowed
```

Using the following code now, all in main.cpp:

```
#include <boost\thread.hpp>
#include <conio.h> 

void thread_func()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime ( 120 );
    boost::this_thread::sleep ( workTime );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::thread t(thread_func);
    _getch();
}
```

Receiving the following errors:

1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __heap_alloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(malloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __recalloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(recalloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __msize already defined in LIBCMT.lib(msize.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in LIBCMT.lib(dbghook.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2005: __isctype_l already defined in LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2005: __isctype already defined in LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: my #include statements aren't coming out right, sorry

Comment: Seems like you mixed up main.h with main.c? The code you present should be placed in a source file, not a header file.

Comment: Appended original post to reflect outcome of changes

Comment: It looks like you're mixing the static debug and release runtimes. You could try adding /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT(D) to your linker options depending on whether you're building in debug or release mode.

Comment: I had the wrong run-time library specified in the project properties.  Needed /MTd (because I'm in debug, which means I'll need /MT for release right?).  I'm an idiot, but than you very much for working though that with me.  If you hadn't said that I would never have checked the project properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `boost::this_thread::sleep ( workTime )` outside of any control flow. You should do something like:

```
void thread_func()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime ( 120 );
    boost::this_thread::sleep ( workTime );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::thread t(thread_func);
    _getch();
}
```